# How to change bot status but only visible in one server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So basically I know how to simply change the bot status with a command, but that's not what i actually want, i want it that when one changes the bot status, the status should only show in that server and stays the same in the others, I'm not sure if that's possible but never know. So I'm stuck here

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def watching(ctx, *,msg):
    server = ctx.message.server
    await client.change_presence(server, game=Game(name=msg, type = 3))
```

Comment: I don't know that this is possible, perhaps you could have a seperate bot for each server though? You only need a new token and could reuse the rest of your scripting  for each bot?

Comment: I want it to be the same bot.. I don't think it's possible too but it may

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible, so the best way to do this would be to remove the bot from the specific discord server, and add an exactly identical bot with a different status to the server. This is somewhat tedious, but I believe this is the only way to do so. If I am wrong, correct me please. Either that, or you could somehow detect which servers its in, and maybe change it according to the server names? I don't know.